# How to obtain inputs within dijit/form/Form?

Tags: javascript, forms, dojo, submit, dijit.form

I's using `dijit/form/Form` to contain my inputs and then encounter problem when I attempt to submit a `dijit/form/Form`, when I have a submit button in this form, it can be submited successfully but redirect to another page (`Spring MVC` acts a server side), and if I remove this submit button I don't know how to get the inputs of this form.

If there is any method for `dijit/form/Form` to get its inputs so that I could submit it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use native form elements (just plain input elements) or `dijit/form` elements (like `dijit/form/TextBox`, ...)?

Comment: My inputs within form are all dijit widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dijit/form/Form` contains a few utilities that work with Dijit form widgets (`dijit/form/TextBox`, `dijit/form/Select`, ...). I don't know if you're using those or not, but the answer is quite similar with or without. The idea is t oserialize your form to an object and to submit that form using AJAX calls.

## With Dijit form widgets

If you use the Dijit form widgets, you can serialize the entire form using [`getValues()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/form/Form#getValues) on your form widget. This will serialize the form for you:

```js
xhr.post("mySubmitUrl", {
    data: registry.byId("myForm").getValues()
}).then(function() {
   console.log("Success"); 
});
```

I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/dtF28/) to demonstrate this.

---

## With native form elements

If you're using native form elements, you have no advantage of using `dijit/form/Form`. To serialize the form you can use the function [`toObject()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/dom-form#toObject) from the `dojo/dom-form` module. This function requires you to pass a form DOM node.

This means you can either pass the domnode of your `dijit/form/Form` widget, or entirely skip this part and just access the DOM node directly.

```js
xhr.post("mySubmitUrl", {
    data: domForm.toObject(registry.byId("myForm").domNode)
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Success"); 
});
```

An example JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/pqSJj/).

---

Now on the server-side (Spring), you just add a method that will handle that specific request, for example:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "mySubmitUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void doPostForm(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("firstname") String firstname) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Hey, @Dimitri M I do really appreciate your very helpful answer. Yes I solved my problem by your answer. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jquery ajax call and inside the data you can pass the values in JSON and success and error page to check if success then load the block as per your requirement and error on if timeout or other errors